# how to insert multiple column/ row values from textarea into mysql

Tags: php

Edited Question:

Thank You for your answers. Sorry for that i am not really looking as per your answers. I want multiple insertion from textarea box while form submission.

i have this result. i want to insert multiple data (both column and rows)  into mysql table using (textarea box) (on form submission)

[image]

when we copy above data to textarea box its look like below

[image]

following source link already done with single column values.. But i want to insert two column values same time in mysql.

https://www.webslesson.info/2019/06/how-to-insert-multiple-data-into-mysql-in-php-using-textarea-field.html

Any one help me for code

i found two discussion page here below same like my question

[How to insert multiple row from textarea to multiple column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128028/how-to-insert-multiple-row-from-textarea-to-multiple-column)

[How to insert multiple value and Multiple rows from textarea to MySQL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015837/how-to-insert-multiple-value-and-multiple-rows-from-textarea-to-mysql-using-php)

---- but from above no answer posted properly...

For eg:
I want to insert following two columns (state,distance(miles) in mysql using textarea box.

Comment: **OH 113.30 WV 146.85 VA 71.25 NC 107.04 SC 228.05 GA 112.76 FL 376.12** is state codes with miles and you want to store it into your table like state_code = OH and state_miles = 113.30 and same with others, right?

Comment: 1st you need to put your table in form and submit it then you can get submited data and insert into mysql , but values of td should be in textarea since you asking for this

Comment: @ChiragKhatri .. yes correct.. i want to store it like three columns in mysql table for eg:
(invoice id, state_code, state_miles)
   11              oh       111.30
   12              wv         54.60
state_code, state_miles datas entered by user in textarea field

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you have to use `<form></form>` tags around the table.
2. Then to get values of each columns in a row, you can use some `<input>` tags inside the `<td>` tags. The reason why doing this is because `<td>` tags don't have a name attribute and thus cannot use `php` `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables
3. Once you have the `name` attribute, use `$_POST` or `$_GET` to capture and transfer to database

You can check this link. This will give you some insight
[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463639/capture-values-of-html-elements-in-a-dynamic-table)